# Using NSPredicate to filter on both Core attribute and entity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities in core data (call them entityOne and entityTwo). I have a entityOne<--->>entityTwo relationship between them.

I am now trying to code an NSPredicate to fetch entityTwo objects on the following basis:

1. Fetch entityTwo objects that have a relationship with a specified entityOne object.
2. Filter out those entityTwo objects which have no value for one of their attributes.

I am best doing both of these in an NSPredicate or is there a better way?

I am trying the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attribute <> "") AND (relationship == entityOne"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Any pointers on coding great fully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Predicate like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entityOneRelationship = %@ AND attribute.length > 0",specifiedEntityOne];
```

Pretty common approach to do that.

Comment: ahhh, it was the string syntax I have wrong. The code you suggested retrieves entities with attributes set to nil. How to retrieve entities with attributes OTHER THAN nil? I have tried both != and <>. Many thanks